# How to define function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, function-construction, symbolic, syntax

I have a 3 by 3 symbolic matrix M(x,y,z).

**Question:1**

First, I want to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. After that I want to make each eigenvalue and eigenvector a function of x,y, and z i.e.

```
(*long expression to calcualte M[kx_,ky_,kz_]*)
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[M[x, y, z]];
(*I want to get expression like
e1[x_,y_,z_]:=first_eigenvalue;
v1[x_,y_,z_]:=first_eigenvector; same for remaining*)
```

I tried `e1[x_,y_,z_]:=vals[[1]]`, it does not work.

**Question:2**

at some point, I want to take `ConjugateTranspose[]` of v1 (or v2, v3). Assuming that like MATLAB, Mathematica also give eigenvector in the column, I defined v1 as `vecs2 = Transpose[vecs]; v1=[[1]];` Now, when I try `ConjugateTranpose[v1];` it gives an erorr that `The first two levels ... can't be transposed`

Comment: `e1 = Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[vals]];
v1 = Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[vecs]];` You can then use them like functions for example `e1[a,b,c]` or `v1[1,2,3]` will substitute the x,y,z values for the arguments.

Comment: `e1[x_, y_, z_] = vals[[1]]` and `v1[x_,y_,z_] = vecs[[1]]` works. I suggest you learn about [immediate and delayed assignments](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html) and how they differ.